# Which windows phone 7 control work the same as UIPageViewController in IOS?

Tags: iphone, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I want to make ebookreader application in windows phone 7. Im finding a library suport effect when i click next or prev page.
It work the same as [this](http://www.techotopia.com/images/a/ab/Iphone_ios_5_uipageviewcontroller_app.jpg) in IOS.
Please let me know, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get (withouit creating a control by yourself) is the [PhoneApplicationPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage%28v=vs.92%29) control. The effect can be added with the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I never use this but there is a control that appears to be identical to your query : [this](http://beemobile4.net/products/metropolis/controls/bookcontrol) (free trial)
or [this](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/68632/68632.aspx) (free)

If this is not what you want, two possibilities:

- You re-create this effect yourself
- You use an existing control but a little different from what you want (like [VolumeGrid](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCp0BA9_xy0))